# Remove all Delayed Jobs for a specific Object in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job

I am using Delayed Jobs in my Rails 5 application.

For example I have a Trip model and am creating two delayed jobs:

```
Trip.delay(run_at: ...).send_reminder
Trip.delay(run_at: ...).get_feedback
```

So I created two delayed jobs.

Now if the Trip gets deleted I want to also delete the delayed jobs and, even more important, if the Trip gets changed, I want to update the jobs (new run_at time), so I would delete and re-create the jobs.

But how can I identify the jobs that belong to the Trip? IS there any method for this? I was trying to add a trip_id column but don't know how to assign the trip_id when creating the new job.

Comment: This page details adding extra columns and an association to the delayed_jobs table: https://sunilkumarn.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/delayed-jobs-in-rails-adding-custom-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Create a Job class for each DelayedJob work like this

```
class TripSendReminderJob < Struct.new(:trip)
  def perform
    # reload use the updated values of a trip, if it was changed
    trip.send_reminder if trip.reload.active? # active? or any method or condition you need to check
  end
end
```

And then, anywhere in your code

```
trip = Trip.find(trip_id)
trip_send_reminder_job = TripSendReminderJob.new(trip)
Delayed::Job.enqueue(trip_send_reminder_job, run_at: ...)
```

Bonus, using a job object like `TripSendReminderJob` allows you to use hooks like before, error, failure, etc. You can see all of them in the [DelayedJob github page](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)